# strange thing happens when I try to get the address of a struct member

Tags: c++, struct

I try to use the get-address operator "&" to get the addresses of some member variables of struct type demo.
But strange thing happens if the member type is char. 
I don't know what's happening. Can anyone help me and explain why? here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct demo{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
    char d;
    char e;
};

int main(){

    demo s;
    s.a = 0;
    s.b = 0.1;
    s.c = 'c';
    s.d = 'd';
    s.e = 'e';

    cout << "address of a:[" <<&s.a <<"]"<< endl;
    cout << "address of b:[" <<&s.b <<"]"<< endl;
    cout << "address of c:[" <<&s.c <<"]"<< endl;
}
```

I compiled the code with g++ and got the following output:

```
address of a:[0x7fff96b9f5c0]
address of b:[0x7fff96b9f5c4]
address of c:[cde]
```

The addresses of s.a and s.b are correctly printed. But why the address of s.c is [cde]?
It seems that when the type is char, &s.c returns some values in(may be near)that memory address. Dose it has something to do with memory alignment in structs ?

Comment: You are right. Sorry for not searching the problem thoroughly. Thanks very much, that post explained very well.

Answer (score 1):

That's the thing about characters, it's trying to print the character that at's the location of `s.c`. That's why it prints out "cde", because the immediate characters after `s.c` are 'd' and 'e' and then most likely a terminating 0.

You can still get the address with `&s.c` and give it to a pointer. The pointer's value will be whatever address is a few bytes after `float b`.

**To fix this** you can cast the address `&s.c` to another data type, like `int`.
That way `cout` won't try to print out the actual characters.
This can be done like so:

```
cout << "address of c:[" << (int*)((int)&s.c) << "]"<< endl;
```

Here we cast the address to an integer, and then back into a pointer so that when we print it it's in the nice pointer-y hex format.
I compiled the new code and got these results:

```
address of a:[0x28fed4]
address of b:[0x28fed8]
address of c:[0x28fedc]
```

Comment: The inner cast to `int` is incorrect, and platform-dependant at-best. At worst it will be outright wrong if `int` is not *identical* to a `char*` in size. Not going into the strict-aliasing diatribe, a proper cast for this is `static_cast<const void*>(&s.c)`. Just `void*` i.e. `static_cast<void*>(&s.c)` will work as well, but I prefer `const` as it eliminates accidental casts from addresses of `const` variables.

Comment: I think casting char* to  const void* type is a great idea, I tried it and it worked! Thank you all very much~~